# develop a plugin on volatility that basically searches a memory dumps to find specific object

Tags: python-2.7, struct, computer-forensics, memory-dump, volatility

How can I develop a plugin on volatility that basically searches a memory dumps to find specific object(structure, record) from struct running on c++, using vtype format?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Memory Forensics](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42608596/868044)